# server AWS incorrectly determines the local time of device

Tags: amazon-web-services, time, amazon-s3, sdk, zone

for example
if a time of current user is 11-00 (the correct time in the user's time zone) AWS SDK return error "The difference between the request time and the current time is too large." 
but if the user sets the local time to 12-00 (the incorrect time in the user's time zone) then the error disappears.
device is a windows phone. 
time zone is Moscow GMT+4.

Comment: This happens in signature validation?

Comment: No. When I try upload file.

Comment: if the time difference between your system time and the actual time is more than 15 mins, AWS will reject your request. Sync up your system time with a NTP server and try your request again.

Comment: error occurs when time is the actual time . error don't occur when time isn't actual